Covariant rule is important in LSP? And how does it impacts the client?
I have been going through LSP with C# and I have a few confusion.
Let just say
public class Employee
{
    //properties
}
    
public class EmployeeExtendedDetail : Employee
{
    //properties
}
    
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    public virtual Employee GetEmployeeDetialById(int id)
    {
        return new Employee();
    }
}

public class EmployeeExtendedDetailRepository : EmployeeRepository
{
    //Changed the return type to a more derived type
    public override EmployeeExtendedDetail GetEmployeeDetialById(int id)
    {
        return new EmployeeExtendedDetail();
    }
}

And in the client:
EmployeeRepository empRepo1 = new EmployeeExtendedDetailRepository();
Employee employee1 = empRepo1.GetEmployeeDetialById(1)

Well what I do not understand in:

LSP: There must be covariance of the return types in the subtype.

First of all should this return type has to be a derived type of Employee? and Employee just fits fine? (probably a stupid question)
Again we cannot change the return type of the method GetEmployeeDetialById to something entirely else which is not a type of Employee.
So what I an not able to see in this rule?

What version of C# are you using?

BTW, I feel this is a misuse of inheritance and is poor software design, because it means a consumer of EmployeeRepository has no way of guaranteeing it can get a EmployeeExtendedDetail object. Furthermore, services are described using interface types, not base classes - an interface IEmployeeRepository is far more useful than a class EmployeeRepository for obvious reasons.

FWIW, your code compiles fine for me using C# 12.0 for .NET 8

@Dai it is c# 9+. Covariance in method return type is allowed

@dai it is about LSP. And to understand the covariance rule in lsp

"LSP" just describes the interface between your editor and the Roslyn C# compiler. There is otherwise nothing special about C# LSP; you're getting this error message because Roslyn is either misconfigured, you've encountered a bug, or a project build error is creating false-positive errors elsewhere. For example, do you have another instance of class Employee in your project?

Also, there are (at least) 3 different implementations of C# LSP - which one are you using?

@Dai I think LSP here refers to Liskov Substitution Principle, not Language Server Protocol.

@Dai Sorry for late reply and unclear question. It is about Liskov Substitution principle.
